# Force login after timeout on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm working on an Android application. I've implemented a timer which redirects the user to the login actvity after a timeout period has expired. This part works well.

The only trouble I'm having is that if the user presses 'back' on the login activity without entering and validating his credentials,  he is able to go back to the previous activity.

Which flags should I start the login activity with so that the user is not able to back press to the previous activity. These are the flags i'm using right now:

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I know that an alternative is to override the behaviour of `onBackPresed()` but that does not sound like good practice to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach sounds good except that it is the Timer's intent that needs to get flagged with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` I believe and not the login activity.

Also, it is considered bad practise to use flags actually, at least moreso than overriding callbacks. 
Im not saying you shouldnt use them tho =P

**<<<<< EDIT: >>>>>**

Actually I think i've misread, try this set of flags instead: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK 
| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, mate. But is it true that Intent flags are discouraged. I've never heard that before. Why is that so? I would think overriding the default workings of device buttons would be more frustrating for users.

Comment: To be honest I dont know why! but i've seen many people snobbing about it on these boards and others. Thanks a lot for the vote and ca!